# genfromtxt import data from csv file issue

Tags: python, macos, csv, numpy, genfromtxt

My csv file(K2CsSb DOS135.csv) is very simple like:

```
-7.21E+00   1.34E-01
-7.16E+00   1.15E-01
-7.13E+00   0.00E+00
-7.10E+00   0.00E+00
-7.07E+00   0.00E+00
```

And I use genfromtxt to import this file like:

```
dosdata = genfromtxt('K2CsSb DOS135.csv',delimiter=',')
```

if I `print(dosdata)`,it shows me:

```
[[-7.21   0.134]
 [-7.16   0.115]
 [-7.13   0.   ]
 ...,
```

I used this 2D array data for interp1d in numpy.

Everything looks perfect. The csv file was edited in MS excel in WINDOWS.

Right now I am using MAC OS X and use mac MS excel editing this file only cut-paste, no change the data type. Then when I import this file as same as before and print. The show me error:
[-7.21   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan]
 f = interp1d(data[:,0], data[:,1])
IndexError: too many indices for array
If I added `dosdata = genfromtxt('K2CsSb DOS135.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None)`
Looks is a tur like:

```
(-7.21, b'1.30E-01\r-7.16E+00', b'1.20E-01\r-7.13E+00', b'0.00E+00\r-7.10E+00', b'0.00E+00\r-7.07E+00')
```

why happen that and how to fix it?

Comment: It is not clear to me if this will fix your problem, but since your file does not use a comma as a delimiter,  don't use the argument `delimiter=','` in `genfromtxt`.

Comment: add this **defaultfmt ="%f"**

Comment: That MAC `\r` (CR) appears to be giving the DOS version problems.  DOS uses (LF/CR), UNIX (LF).  I'm a little surprised that `delimiter=','` works, since you don't have `,` in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution. 
In mac excel , using save as... has two type of csv. One is MS-DOS csv; another is Microsoft csv.
Choose Microsoft csv could solve the problem.